Por que me da error 404 para ver una view creada en codeIgniter con la ruta que cree
Cree una view, model, controller y una route, pero cuando ingreso la ruta en chrome usando localhost y la ubicacion y llego hasta mi carpeta de trabajo me da error 404, pero si uso la ruta por default que trae codeIgniter y coloco ahi mi controlador en lugar de el controlador Home por defecto entonces si muestra la view.

Bienvenido! te sugiero que revises https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y reformules tu pregunta, ahora mismo falta mucha información para poder ayudarte.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
